# Negations of Statements

Tags: first-order-logic

I'm currently working in topology and I was trying to prove something by the contrapositive, but I was unable to do so because I struggled to understand how I should appropriately interpret the negation of a given statement. The particular form of statement that is essential to the proof is of the general form:

> $S$: An object $x$ with property $A$ also has property $P$.

So, in attempting to devise the negation of this statement, I took two possible routes.

**Answer 1:** $\neg S:$ An object $x$ with property $A$ does not have property $P$

**Answer 2:** $\neg S:$ An object $x$ without property $A$ does not have property $P$.

So ultimately, this comes down to a question of "at what point do I start and stop the negations?"  In Answer 1, object $x$ preserves its initial property but does not preserve its concluding property, whereas in Answer 2, object $x$ has neither initial nor concluding property. Which answer is the correct one, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is statement $S$ supposed to mean:  *Every* object $x$ that has property $A$ also has property $P$?  If so, then the negation would be:  There is at least one object $x$ that has property $A$ but does not have property $P$.

Answer (score 1):

$S: \forall x: A \implies P,\;$ ie $S: \forall x: \lnot A \lor P$

The negation becomes $\lnot S: \exists x: A \land \lnot P$

This sounds like your Answer 1, but you need to be more precise.